# Ignore first 8 lines of txt file when reading ? c#

Tags: c#, streamreader

I want to ignore the part in the blue box and start reading my txt file from the arrow

[image]

I'm planning on just looping through first 8 lines and storing them in a junk variable. If I do this will my crusor now be at the 9th line so I can start reading from there? My code's definitely wrong, it doesn't even read the first 8 lines.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));


            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                string junk = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            sr.Dispose();

        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't read those lines?

Comment: walk thru it with the debugger

Comment: How big is the file? You could read all with a single call

Answer (score 10):

You can use this:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(ofd.FileName);

foreach (string line in lines.Skip(8))
    Trace.WriteLine(line);
```

Because the `File.ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, the lines are only loaded when iterated.

More info: *File.ReadLines Method* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx

Comment: I tried using this but file.readlines kept getting underlined in red (i think i'm missing some libraries?)

Comment: This is available since .NET 4.0 and higher. Look for more info at the link i provided.

Answer (score 0):

It's a dumb aproach but it works.
You have to consume the line.

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"TextFile1.txt");

        int i = 1;

        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            if(i > 8)
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine ());
            sr.ReadLine ();
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: i tried to use this but 1) shouldnt it be i<8?
2) it doesn't work. I mean it doesn't even display the first line out of the 8 to my textbox when i do textBox1.Text = sr.ReadLine();